# Kafka to Elasticsearch connector not able to start

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

**Elasticsearch** -> elasticsearch-7.6.0

I am trying to move data from Kafka topic to Elasticsearch by using Elasticsearch Sink connector.
But starting the connector is showing below error

```
2022-05-28 09:39:27,864] ERROR [SINK_ELASTIC_TEST_01|task-0] Failed to create mapping for index users.user_details3 with schema Schema{STRING} due to 'ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [type : text] [fields : {keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}]]]' after 6 attempt(s) (io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.RetryUtil:164)
ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [type : text] [fields : {keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}]]]
        at org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXContent(BytesRestResponse.java:178)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:2484)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:2461)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2184)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2154)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:2118)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.putMapping(IndicesClient.java:440)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.lambda$createMapping$3(ElasticsearchClient.java:238)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.RetryUtil.callWithRetries(RetryUtil.java:158)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.RetryUtil.callWithRetries(RetryUtil.java:119)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.callWithRetries(ElasticsearchClient.java:426)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.createMapping(ElasticsearchClient.java:236)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.checkMapping(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:151)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.tryWriteRecord(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:294)
        at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.put(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:118)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:584)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:334)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:235)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:204)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:200)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:255)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
        Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [PUT], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/users.user_details3/_mapping?master_timeout=30s&timeout=30s], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
```

Topic data

```
rowtime: 2022/05/27 13:46:48.136 Z, key: {"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"{"_id": {"_data": "826290D642000000022B022C0100296E5A100429BEBD4C4B7F4C0BA80B881299B5FF9246645F696400646290D642F23DB1FBE13668180004"}}"}, value: {"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"{"_id": {"_data": "826290D642000000022B022C0100296E5A100429BEBD4C4B7F4C0BA80B881299B5FF9246645F696400646290D642F23DB1FBE13668180004"}, "operationType": "insert", "clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1653659202, "i": 2}}, "fullDocument": {"_id": {"$oid": "6290d642f23db1fbe1366818"}, "userid": 1.0, "name": "Gaurav"}, "ns": {"db": "users", "coll": "user_details3"}, "documentKey": {"_id": {"$oid": "6290d642f23db1fbe1366818"}}}"}, partition: 0
rowtime: 2022/05/27 13:47:06.142 Z, key: {"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"{"_id": {"_data": "826290D654000000012B022C0100296E5A100429BEBD4C4B7F4C0BA80B881299B5FF9246645F696400646290D654F23DB1FBE13668190004"}}"}, value: {"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"{"_id": {"_data": "826290D654000000012B022C0100296E5A100429BEBD4C4B7F4C0BA80B881299B5FF9246645F696400646290D654F23DB1FBE13668190004"}, "operationType": "insert", "clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1653659220, "i": 1}}, "fullDocument": {"_id": {"$oid": "6290d654f23db1fbe1366819"}, "userid": 1.0, "name": "Gaurav"}, "ns": {"db": "users", "coll": "user_details3"}, "documentKey": {"_id": {"$oid": "6290d654f23db1fbe1366819"}}}"}, partition: 0
rowtime: 2022/05/27 13:47:24.149 Z, key: {"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"{"_id": {"_data": "826290D668000000012B022C0100296E5A100429BEBD4C4B7F4C0BA80B881299B5FF9246645F696400646290D668F23DB1FBE136681A0004"}}"}, value: {"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"{"_id": {"_data": "826290D668000000012B022C0100296E5A100429BEBD4C4B7F4C0BA80B881299B5FF9246645F696400646290D668F23DB1FBE136681A0004"}, "operationType": "insert", "clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1653659240, "i": 1}}, "fullDocument": {"_id": {"$oid": "6290d668f23db1fbe136681a"}, "userid": 1.0, "name": "Gaurav"}, "ns": {"db": "users", "coll": "user_details3"}, "documentKey": {"_id": {"$oid": "6290d668f23db1fbe136681a"}}}"}, partition: 0
rowtime: 2022/05/27 13:48:00.156 Z, key: {"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"{"_id": {"_data": "826290D68A000000012B022C0100296E5A100429BEBD4C4B7F4C0BA80B881299B5FF9246645F696400646290D68AF23DB1FBE136681B0004"}}"}, value: {"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"{"_id": {"_data": "826290D68A000000012B022C0100296E5A100429BEBD4C4B7F4C0BA80B881299B5FF9246645F696400646290D68AF23DB1FBE136681B0004"}, "operationType": "insert", "clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1653659274, "i": 1}}, "fullDocument": {"_id": {"$oid": "6290d68af23db1fbe136681b"}, "userid": 1.0, "name": "Gaurav"}, "ns": {"db": "users", "coll": "user_details3"}, "documentKey": {"_id": {"$oid": "6290d68af23db1fbe136681b"}}}"}, partition: 0
rowtime: 2022/05/27 13:50:00.182 Z, key: {"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"{"_id": {"_data": "826290D706000000012B022C0100296E5A100429BEBD4C4B7F4C0BA80B881299B5FF9246645F696400646290D706F23DB1FBE136681C0004"}}"}, value: {"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"{"_id": {"_data": "826290D706000000012B022C0100296E5A100429BEBD4C4B7F4C0BA80B881299B5FF9246645F696400646290D706F23DB1FBE136681C0004"}, "operationType": "insert", "clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1653659398, "i": 1}}, "fullDocument": {"_id": {"$oid": "6290d706f23db1fbe136681c"}, "userid": 2.0, "name": "Gaurav"}, "ns": {"db": "users", "coll": "user_details3"}, "documentKey": {"_id": {"$oid": "6290d706f23db1fbe136681c"}}}"}, partition: 0
```

**ElasticSearchSink Configuration**

```
{
  "name": "SINK_ELASTIC_TEST_01",
  "config": {
    "type.name": "kafka-connect",
    "name": "SINK_ELASTIC_TEST_01",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "errors.log.enable": "true",
    "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
    "topics": "users.user_details3",
    "connection.url": "http://localhost:9200",
    "connection.username": "",
    "connection.password": "",
    "key.ignore": "true",
    "schema.ignore": "false"
  }
}
```

Please see I am creating topic from MongoDB source connector , so on a high level I am trying to achieve this

```
MongoDB --> MongoDBSourceConnector--> Kafka --> ElasticSearchSinkConnector --> ElasticSearch
```

Please find the MongoDBSourceConnector Configuration for reference

```
{
  "name": "source-mongodb-kafka-stream",
  "config": {
    "name": "source-mongodb-kafka-stream",
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "connection.uri": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    "database": "users",
    "collection": "",
    "topic.prefix": ""
  }
}
```

**Update 06-03-2022 after OneCricketeer comments**
I have created an index in Elasticsearch with the same name as topic

```
PUT /users_generic/_doc/1
{
   "id":{
      "_data":"826290D706000000012B022C0100296E5A100429BEBD4C4B7F4C0BA80B881299B5FF9246645F696400646290D706F23DB1FBE136681C0004"
   },
   "operationType":"insert",
   "clusterTime":{
      "$timestamp":{
         "t":1653659398,
         "i":1
      }
   },
   "fullDocument":{
      "id":{
         "$oid":"6290d706f23db1fbe136681c"
      },
      "userid":2.0,
      "name":"Gaurav"
   },
   "ns":{
      "db":"users",
      "coll":"user_details3"
   },
   "documentKey":{
      "id":{
         "$oid":"6290d706f23db1fbe136681c"
      }
   }
}
```

With above step , mapping is been created , now when I again executed the connector with same parameters as above , it throws me a different effort

```
2-06-03 12:39:16,691] ERROR [SINK_ELASTIC_TEST_01|task-0] Failed to execute bulk request due to 'org.elasticsearch.common.compress.NotXContentException: Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes' after 6 attempt(s) (io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.RetryUtil:164)
org.elasticsearch.common.compress.NotXContentException: Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes
```

Comment: Create the index mapping before running the connector. Also, you probably don't want your payload to be only a string (from Mongo) if you actually want to search any of the fields in Elastic

Comment: @OneCricketeer Can you please help me (updated), I am struggling to set this since 2 weeks now

Comment: I haven't used Elasticsearch in years; I'm not familiar with this error, but I said to create a mapping, not an actual document https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/mapping.html#create-mapping Also, you converters should match (switch Mongo to StringConverter, for example)